# Gatsby Develop : Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I just did a git clone off a starter template on Gatsby-- bumped into this error when I ran 'gatsby develop'. I've deleted the node module, as well as the sharp module in node module. To no avail.
Do let me know what's going on at this point! :-)

```html
PS C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter> gatsby develop
success open and validate gatsby-configs - 0.073s

 ERROR 


Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

Cannot find module '../build/Release/sharp.node'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\lib\constructor.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\safe-sharp.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\extend-node-type.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\gatsby-node.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\resolve-module-exports.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\validate.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\load.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\load-plugins\index.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\bootstrap\index.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby\dist\commands\develop-process.js
- C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\.cache\tmp-19076-nq3SvOAJn7yo

- Remove the "node_modules/sharp" directory, run "npm install" and look for errors
- Consult the installation documentation at https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/en/stable/install/
- Search for this error at https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues
```

Ran 'npm build' here

```html
C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\src\stats.cc(130,1): error C2661: 'v8::Object::Set': no overloa 
ded function takes 2 arguments [C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\build\sharp.vcxproj]
C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\src\stats.cc(140,20): warning C4834: discarding return value of 
 function with 'nodiscard' attribute [C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\build\sharp.vcxproj]      
C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\src\pipeline.cc(1017,20): warning C4834: discarding return valu 
e of function with 'nodiscard' attribute [C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp\build\sharp.vcxproj]  
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ipche\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\gatsby-transformer-sharp\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v14.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! sharp@0.22.1 install: `(node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the sharp@0.22.1 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-06T21_03_57_721Z-debug.log
```

By the way, I went to package.json and changed the dependency version of sharp to 'sharp@0.22.1'. It was previously sharp@0.26.1!

Any leads?

**EDIT**
Ran ' npm install --verbose sharp'

```html
 1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:11.67
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:194:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:276:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\ipche\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" 
"rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\sharp
gyp ERR! node -v v14.13.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.22.1~install: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.22.1~install: PATH: C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\sharp\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Python38\Scripts\;C:\Python38\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\ipche\anaconda3;C:\Users\ipche\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\ipche\anaconda3\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\ipche\anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\ipche\anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\python;C:\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\python\Scripts;C:\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\bin;C:\Users\ipche\Documents\GitHub\feelDetection\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\python;C:\Users\ipche\Documents\GitHub\feelDetection\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\python\Scripts;C:\Users\ipche\Documents\GitHub\feelDetection\Panda3D-1.10.6-x64\bin;C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm
npm verb lifecycle sharp@0.22.1~install: CWD: C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\sharp
npm info lifecycle sharp@0.22.1~install: Failed to exec install script
npm timing action:install Completed in 15700ms
npm verb unlock done using C:\Users\ipche\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_locks\staging-4a5f00369a03df36.lock for C:\Users\ipche\gatsby-strapi-starter\node_modules\.staging
npm timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 250ms
npm timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 39766ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the node_module folder first and then try out the below-given methods! This works for me

Update the version of the sharp package manually in the package.json file and then try to run the command `npm i sharp`

or first, install sharp package and then run the command `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, you may need extra dependencies to make the sharp module work. Try running:

```
npm install --global windows-build-tools --vs2015
```

Upon installing this package, it downloads and installs Visual C++ Build Tools 2015, provided free of charge by Microsoft. These tools are required to compile popular native modules. It will also install Python 2.7, configuring your machine, and npm appropriately.

Check [Gatsby on Windows docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-on-windows/) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

On my Windows machine another possible solution is to update all the related gatsby plugins (for images).
I did it with yarn, of course, as suggested delete the node modules beforehand.

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

Pick the onces you need, hope that solves the errors.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be anything but what worked for me was downgrading my nodejs version, specifically to **`14.15.0`** using `nvm`.
steps to follow :

- Downgrade nodejs version.
- Delete any `package-lock.json` or `yarn-lock.json` from the root folder.
- Delete `node_modules` folder.
- Delete `.cache` folder.
- Run `npm install` or `yarn install`.
  Hopefully, it will fix the issue, if it doesn't you can refer to the issues page of the library and more specifically on [this issue](https://github.com/lovell/sharp/issues/3022)

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby has an answer for this [here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-sharp/#incompatible-library-version-sharpnode-requires-version-x-or-later-but-z-provides-version-y).

> To fix this, you’ll need to update all Gatsby plugins in the current project that depend on the sharp package. Here’s a list of official plugins that you might need to update in case your projects uses them:

```
gatsby-plugin-sharp
gatsby-plugin-manifest
gatsby-remark-images-contentful
gatsby-source-contentful
gatsby-transformer-sharp
gatsby-transformer-sqip
```

> To update these packages, run:

```
npm install gatsby-plugin-sharp gatsby-plugin-manifest gatsby-remark-images-contentful gatsby-source-contentful gatsby-transformer-sharp gatsby-transformer-sqip
```

> If updating these doesn’t fix the issue, your project probably uses
> other plugins from the community that depend on a different version of
> sharp. Try running npm list sharp or yarn why sharp to see all
> packages in the current project that use sharp and try updating them
> as well.